# TSM rebuild complete backup after operating system migration

Tags: backup, tsm

I have a server with several mounted external drives from JBODs. This server ensures that the backup is done using TSM software. This server now had an operating system migration due to end-of-life. The location of the drives and the config of the backup remain untouched. However, now the backup is completely rebuilt, sending several unnecessary terabytes of files already in the backup.
Is there a way to delete redundant files in the backup? Can I check which files will be sent before the scheduled backup?